# How to select a row in table view when it reach a specific position?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to select a table view row when the person reaches the center of the table view. Basically whenever the table reaches a point y I want the cell at that point to be selected.

I imagine it is similar to uiPickerView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `UITableViewController` you should implement `-scrollViewDidScroll:` like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (prevCell != nil)
        self.prevCell.selected = NO;

    CGPoint offset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    CGPoint point = offset;
    point.y += self.tableView.center.y;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selected = YES;
    self.prevCell = cell;
}
```

This is tested and works. `prevCell` is a property of type `UITableViewCell`.

You must get the current offset of the scroll view for the table view and add this to the position of the cell you want (in this example, I take the cell in the center of the table view).
Then, using `-indexPathForRowAtPoint:` we grab the index path for the cell at the point and using `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` we get the cell for the index path. Set it to selected and store it for later use (to deselect it on the next scroll).

Comment: Spice this up using `[self.prevCell setSelected:NO animated:YES]` and `[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES]`. Gives a "nice effect".

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
[[yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[yourTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:wantPoint]] setSelected:true]
```

?

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be achieved by getting all visible indexpaths, then data on visible indexpaths. The best answer you may see your own cz you know your problem well. Go through this class reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: What does "you may see your own cz" mean? I wonder if this answer needs editing.